# How to directly convert a Dictionary to a Codable instance in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, codable

My app receives binary data from our server. In my old Objective-C code, I handle the response data as follows:

1. Use NSJSONSerialization to convert NSData to NSDictionary, which contains data like: {"code": "0", "info": {"user_id": 123456}},
2. Write a MTLModel subclass
3. Use Mantle API to convert the above **info** dictionary, which is {"user_id": 123456}, into my model

Now I 'd like to use Swift to do this, and I just learnt how convenience Codable protocol is. However, looks like with this protocol implemented, I can only convert it with Data/NSData, which makes the above procedures become this:

1. Same as above
2. Write a struct/class that conforms to Codable protocol
3. Use NSJSONSerialization to encode **info** dictionary, which is {"user_id": 123456}, into Data/NSData again
4. Use JSONDecoder to decode this data into my model

So my question is, can a Codable object be derived directly from a dictionary?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers from you guys, but let me clarify it a bit.
Although the response JSON format is somewhat fixed, there are many different requests and responses, so the **info** part is different. For example:

- R1: {"code": "0", "info": {"user_id": 123456}} is the response of a user id request
- R2: {"code": "0", "info": {"temperature": 20, "country": "London"}} is the response of a weather temperature request

Therefore, the **Codable** class/struct should be constructed from only the **info** part, instead of the whole response data, and that's why I can't simply apply step 2 & 4 to accomplish that.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can decode directly in step 1. `let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeClass.self, from: data)` where `SomeClass` is your custom class and `data´ the data you receive from the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have JSON that looks like this:

```
let r1 = Data("""
{"code": "0", "info": {"user_id": 123456}}
""".utf8)

let r2 = Data("""
{"code": "0", "info": {"temperature": 20, "country": "London"}}
""".utf8)
```

And "info" types that look like this:

```
struct UserID: Codable {
    var userId: Int
}

struct WeatherTemperature: Codable {
    var temperature: Int
    var country: String
}
```

I'm assuming a decoder that does the snakeCase conversion (you can replace this by implementing CodingKeys or whatever):

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

Given that, you need a generic Response type:

```
struct Response<Info: Codable>: Codable {
    var code: String
    var info: Info
}
```

And with that, you can decode your response directly from the JSON object:

```
let userID = try decoder.decode(Response<UserID>.self, from: r1).info
let weather = try decoder.decode(Response<WeatherTemperature>.self, from: r2).info
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it could be solved by Generic, but I just didn't know its syntax.

Answer (score 3):

No, not directly, and yes, sort of.  Confused?  I'll explain.

`Codable` is meant to encode/decode to/from `Data`, with JSON being the most popular encoding these days, but you can also use plist or write your own custom encoder/decoder.

But sticking with the standard encoders, if you want to go from a `Dictionary` to a type that conforms to `Decodable`, which includes anything that conforms to `Codable`, you would do it by encoding the `Dictionary` as JSON (or plist) and then decode the resulting `Data` into the `Decodable` thing... which is basically the process you describe.  Note that if the `Dictionary`'s key and value types are both `Codable` (for example `[String: Int]`), you can use JSONEncoder/Decoder instead of `JSONSerialization`.  However, if it's, for example, `[String: Any]`, you'll need to stay with `JSONSerialization`, because `Any` does not conform to `Codable`.

With that said, you can extend `Decodable` to include a failable or throwing initializer that takes `Dictionary`, in which you encode the dictionary to `Data` and then decode using `JSONDecoder`.  It's still exactly the process you're already doing, except that anything that's `Decodable` will automatically have it available for easy use.

```swift
extension Decodable
{
    init<Key: Hashable, Value>(_ dict: [Key: Value]) throws where Key: Codable, Value: Codable
    {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't sound like you actually need *any* codable thing to be initializable from a `Dictionary`, just your model.  In that case, rather than extend `Decodable`, just extend your model.

You can do a similar trick with `JSONSerialization`, if you have `Any` or other non-`Codable` values in your dictionary:

```swift
extension Decodable
{
    init<Key: Hashable>(_ dict: [Key: Any]) throws
    {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```swift
struct MyModel: Codable {...}

let dict: [String: Any] = getDictionarySomehow()

let myModel = try MyModel(dict)
```

Comment: Getting the error: Non-nominal type 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') cannot be extended

Comment: I'm sure that's a mistake on my part.  It should work if you extend `Decodable` instead.  `Codable` should inherit from it since its a combination of `Encodable` and `Decodable`.  It's been a while since I wrote that, so I'm surprised you're the first to catch it, or at least the first to catch it and mention it.

Comment: I've updated my answer and confirmed the code now compiles.  Sorry it didn't before.  I could have sworn I double-checked back then, but it was a few months ago, and my memory of exactly what I did when I answered is a bit hazy.  Thanks for mentioning it so I could correct my answer.

Comment: Hey Chip, thanks for correcting it. But do we have an example of how we can use this initializer?
I have a use case where I have a dictionary [String: Any] and want to convert it into a Codable model.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj, if I understand you correctly, you'll need to modify it a bit.  The problem is the `Any` values in your dictionary.  You'd need the initializer to take a `[String: Any]` and use `JSONSerialization` instead of `JSONEncoder`.  You still use `JSONDecoder` to decode your model.  To use it, you just pass your dictionary to the initializer (`let model = try MyModel(dictionary: myDictionary)`

Comment: Of course, that depends on the `[String:Any]` being encodable into JSON that can then be decoded into your model, but that's true of the `JSONEncoder` version too - it just guarantees that dictionary can be encoded into some valid JSON, because both the keys and values have to conform to `Codable`.  There is no such guarantee for `[String: Any]`, but neither version can guarantee that the dictionary represents your model except by throwing when it tries to decode.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj I added how to do it with `JSONSerialization` (so you can use `[String: Any]` and how to use it.

Comment: Wow! Cool one! Thanks Chip!

Comment: Hi @ChipJarred. I am at a similar situation. I want to convert my dictionary [String: Any] to a model. struct SettingsModel: Codable {
    let key: String
    let value: Any?

    init(key: String, value: Any) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}
And I have pasted the Decodable extension you suggested above. But still, I get the Type 'SettingsModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' error. Pls help.

Comment: @Mano, you get that for your `SettingsModel` doesn't conform to `Decodable` because its `value` property is `Any?` which doesn't conform to `Decodable`.   You'll either need to implement your own `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` initializer, specify a type for `value` that does conform to `Decodable`, or use a different method.  The extension that uses `JSONSerialization` is for initializing a `Decodable` from a `Dictionary` that may contain `Any` values, but it still requires that the thing you're decoding into fully conforms to `Decodable`, which is not the case for your `SettingsModel`.

Comment: BTW to conform to `Codable`, if you keep `value` as `Any?`, you'll also need write a custom `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws`, because `Codable` is a join of `Encodable` and `Decodable`.  So if you want it to conform to `Codable`, you'll need to conform to both which means either using only properties that are `Codable` so the compiler can synthesize conformance for you, or explicitly conforming to both `Encodable` and `Decodable` by writing the `init(from:) throws` and `encode(to:) throws` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Convert json string to data and then convert to codable struct using json decoder

```
let json = "{\"CustomerTypeID\":3,\"CustomerID\":4330,\"CustomerName\":\"Black :)\",\"CustomerTypeName\":\"Member\",\"IsWalkedInCustomer\":false,\"Email\":\"black@yopmail.com\",\"Mobile\":\"+447400369852\",\"AllowPartPaymentOnCore\":true,\"ServiceBookingList\":[{\"SaleStatusTypeID\":2,\"SaleStatusTypeName\":\"Paid\",\"ServiceName\":\"Nail Polish Service\",\"BookingStatusTypeID\":1,\"BookingStatusTypeName\":\"Booked\",\"SaleID\":71861,\"ID\":83756,\"ServiceCategoryID\":85,\"ServiceID\":173,\"ServicePackageID\":245,\"Price\":0.00,\"TotalPrice\":0.00,\"CleaningTimeInMinute\":10,\"StartDate\":\"2021-06-30T00:00:00Z\",\"StartTime\":\"11:00:00\",\"EndTime\":\"11:30:00\",\"AssignedToStaffID\":268,\"FacilityID\":0,\"Description\":\"\",\"IsPartialPaid\":false,\"TotalAmountPaid\":0.0,\"SaleRefundAmount\":0.00,\"AssignedToStaffName\":\"Iqra Rasheed\",\"CustomerMembershipID\":null,\"Duration\":\"00:30\",\"LastUpdatedByName\":\"Iqra Rasheed\",\"FacilityName\":\"\",\"StaffImagePath\":\"Staff_fabf1c3a-e2bf-45c6-b7f1-3cddd17fb358.jpg\",\"TotalTaxPercentage\":22.00,\"TotalDiscountAmount\":0.00,\"IsFree\":false,\"HasUnSubmittedForm\":true,\"HasAtleastOneMandatoryForm\":true}]}"
        
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
        
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
if let data = data, let model = try? decoder.decode(YourCodableModel.self, from: data) {
    print(model)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
  "code": "0",
  "info": {
           "user_id": 123456
          }
 }
```

So as discussed above you can do this in one step as long as your structs match.

for instance:

```
 struct ServerResponse: Codable {
      var code: Int
      var info: [String:Int]
 }
```

alternatively:

```
struct ServerResponse: Codable {
      var code: Int
      var info: Info
}

struct Info: Codable {
     var user_id: Int
}
```

Then simply

```
 let serverResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse.self, from: your_server_json_data)
```